# How to enable button from otherJFrame after disabeling it in Main JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I have two classes:

```
public class Screen1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
...
//disables JButton1 after it is clicked on
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
      setVisible(false);  
....
}
}
```

And another class:

```
public class Screen2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
...
//Clicking on JButton2 is supposed to enable JButton1 (from Screen1) again     
...
}
```

Now, what is the easiest way to enable JButton1 again? I don't have direct access to JButton1 from Screen1 to set is visible again. I've looked into *ActionListeners* and *Modal JDialogs* which seemed from my Google search like some promising ways to solve this (possibly?).
But I can't really find an example that I would understand (I'm more of a Java beginner).

Any helpful input is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you should consider implementing some kind of [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) which the first class can use to monitor for changes made by the second and update it's state accordingly

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 1):

Please find below this simple example

Screen2 contains a `JButton` disabled by default, and Screen1 contains another `JButton` that can enable the first button.

#### Screen2

```
public class Screen2 extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;

    public Screen2() {
        button = new JButton("Button");
        button.setEnabled(false); //the button is disabled by default
        this.add(button);// add the button to the screen
    }

    // this method will be used to enable the button
    public void changeButtonStatus(boolean flag) {
        button.setEnabled(flag);
    }
}
```

#### Screen1

```
public class Screen1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Screen1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(250, 200);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        JButton button = new JButton("Enable the button");
        Screen2 screen2 = new Screen2();
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                screen2.changeButtonStatus(true); //Call the method that enable the button
            }
        });
        frame.add(screen2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(button, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Output

First, the Screen2 `JButton` was disabled

[image]

When clicking on the Screen1 `JButton`, the Screen2 `JButton` will enable.

[image]